# Synchronous SmtpClient send, doesn't hit SendCompleted handler

Tags: c#

```
 SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("my.server.com");
```

I am creating the client as usual and send an email. All works fine, the email arrives in the box correctly.

Still i want to do some work in code inside the SendCompleted event handler.

```
  client.SendCompleted += client_SendCompleted;
```

I'm starting the work without the async option,

```
client.Send(message);
```

but this way, my handler code is never hit.

If i choose client.SendAsync(), the event handler gets executed but i have to do some synchronizations to get it right and maybe there is an easier way for this..

So my question , when i use send without async, is it normal to not hit the handler?

Comment: The handler is only fired for async. If you are calling Send synchronously just put whatever code you would have executed in the handler after your call to Send.

Comment: This is pretty much the answer.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll in that handler i was checking for a correct sending, using the e.error as a response. i can put my code after that call to send, but how can i be sure my message was sent?

Comment: wrap your call to Send in try/catch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are sending synchronously then your completed handler will never fire because the associated event is only triggered for async calls.

In a synchronous call, just put whatever code you would have put in your handler after your call to Send:

```
client.Send(message);
//TODO: Put your handler code here.
```